# Заполнение столбцов в DF по условию (со смещением)

Tags: python, база-данных, pandas, dataframe

Итак, есть исходный DF с одним столбцом:

```
  x1
-300 
 200 
 100 
 100 
 200 
-50 
 30 
 20 
 10
```

Создаем второй столбец x2 по условию: если предыдущий x1<0, то x2 = x1 текущий+ предыдущий. Но если предыдущий x2 был <0, то текущий x2= x1 тек+x2 пред. 
Если же x2 тек. >0 , и x1 след. >0, то x2 след. = x1 след. 
А третий столбец x3: если X2<=0 , то X3=0, если X2>0 - то X3=x2

На выходе должны получить нечто такое:

```
  x1    x2      x3
-300             -   
 200    -100     -   
 100     -       -   
 100     100     100 
 200     200     200 
-50     -50      -   
 30     -20      -   
 20      -       -   
 10      10      10
```

Comment: можете пояснить появление `-50` в `x2`?

Comment: До этого было 200 - 200. Поэтому на след. год значение зануляется, но у нас x1 (-50) , поэтому и x2 (-50)

Comment: А откуда у вас пропуски в `x2`, ведь в `x1` нет ни одного нулевого элемента, соответственно все сторки в `x2` должны быть заполнены?

Comment: Изменять смысл вопроса после того как на него был получен ответ(ы) - некорректно, т.к. это скорее всего инвалидирует ответы...

Comment: Прошу прощения, условия довольны сложны для описания, поэтому так происходит. В любом случае ответ не совпадает с тем, что я ожидал ( по изначальному условию)